# Немогу правильно связать функции в задаче " при отметке чек-бокса в строке появляется числовое значение"

Tags: javascript, html5

По задаче: дано 8 чек-боксов, символизирующих 8 разрядное число в двоичной системе и строка, в которой это число отображается в десятичной системе . Необходимо чтобы при установке галочки или её снятия с чекбокса менялось отбражение  соответсвующего числа в строке. Обязательное требование :  отображения в браузере чекбоксов и строки, манипуляции с чекбоксами выражаются в форме алгоритма вывода элементов и работы с элементами массива.

```js
function forma(type, formname) {
 document.write("<" + type + "name="+formname+">")
 for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) 
 {
  if (i == 9) 
  {
  document.write("<input type='text' id=" + forma.arguments[i]+"></input>");
  }
  else
  {
  document.write("<input type='checkbox' name=" + forma.arguments[i]+" onchange = 'nsChange("+formname+")' ></input>");
  }
 }
 document.write("</" + type + ">")
  }

function nsChange(formname)
{
for (var i = 1; i < 9; i++);
if(formname.arguments[i].checked)
  {
  arguments[i] = Math.pow (2,(i-1));
   nresulttenD(arguments);
  }
else
  {
  arguments[i] = 0;
  nresulttenD(arguments);
  }

}
 function nresulttenD(mas)
{
var S =mas[9];
for (var i=1; i<8; i++)
{
mas[9] += mas[i];
}

 document.getElementById('digit').value = mas[9];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Заголовок страницы</title>

<scriptsrc="D:\trening.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<script>
 forma("form", "form_tests");
 nsChange("form_tests");
</script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: В чем собственно ошибка?

Comment: чего то тут явно не хватает, я непонимаю смысла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function generate() {
 for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
  document.write("<input type='checkbox' name='ch_"+(i+1)+"' onChange = 'chChange()' />");
 }
 document.write("<input type='text' name = 'result' />");
 
}

function chChange(){
 s = 0; v = 1;
 for (var i = 7; i >= 0; i--){
   if(document.forms[0].elements[i].checked){
  s += v;
  
    }
    
    v *= 2;
    document.forms[0].result.value = s;
 }
 
 
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE!>
<html>
<head>
<title>Загловок страницы</title>
<script src="D:\web2\trening.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<script>
 generate();
</script>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $d = document, 
    bitsEl, rsltEl; 

$d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  bitsEl = $d.getElementById('bits'), 
  rsltEl = $d.querySelector('#result > span'); 
  for (let i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
    bitsEl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
      <div><label>${i}
        <input data-bit="${i}" type="checkbox">
      </label></div>
    `); 
  }
  bits = Array.from(bitsEl.querySelectorAll('input[data-bit]')); 
  bits.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', onBitsClick)); 
});

function onBitsClick() {
  let chkd = Array.from(bitsEl.querySelectorAll('input[data-bit]:checked')); 
  let decimal = 0; 
  chkd.forEach(el => decimal |= 1 << +el.dataset.bit); 
  rsltEl.textContent = decimal; 
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center; 
  height: calc(100vh - 20px); 
  font: 20px monospace; 
}

#bits { display: flex; }
#bits div {
  width: 2.5ch; 
  text-align: center; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  color: #aaa; 
}
#bits div:not(:first-child) { margin-left: -1px; }

#result {
  display: inline-block; 
  position: relative; 
  width: calc(2.5ch * 8 + 7px); height: 3.35em; 
  margin-top: -1px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
#result > span {
  display: inline-block; 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0.1em; top: 0; right: 0.1em; bottom: 0; 
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: right; 
}
```

```html
<form name="test">
  <div id="bits"></div>
  <span id="result"><span>0</span></span>
</form>
```

Вот только нинада говорить что `forEach()` - это не работа с элементами массива :D